# How to make flexible columns by content?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

### How to make flexible columns by content?

In this case, I need 4 columns if there is everything okay, but in any cases if list item is bigger than it needed I need make less columns. Prefer only CSS solution.
It is logical that this `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(min-content, 1fr));` expression should have worked, but min-content and max-content is not working with "fr" units.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 450px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #d4d1d1;
}

.wrapper:first-child {
  background-color: #cc8b8b;
}

.list {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  // grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(min-content, 25%));
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px dashed green;
}

.list__item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.list__item-img {
  width: 91px;
  height: 91px;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="list__item">
        <div class="list__item-img"></div>
        <span class="list__item-caption">Lorem</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item">
        <div class="list__item-img"></div>
        <span class="list__item-caption">Lorem</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item">
        <div class="list__item-img"></div>
        <span class="list__item-caption">Lorem</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item">
        <div class="list__item-img"></div>
        <span class="list__item-caption">Lorem</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item">
        <div class="list__item-img"></div>
        <span class="list__item-caption">Lorem</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item">
        <div class="list__item-img"></div>
        <span class="list__item-caption">Lorem</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item">
        <div class="list__item-img"></div>
        <span class="list__item-caption">Lorem</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item">
        <div class="list__item-img"></div>
        <span class="list__item-caption">Lorem</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item">
        <div class="list__item-img"></div>
        <span class="list__item-caption">Lorem</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="list__item">
        <div class="list__item-img"></div>
        <span class="list__item-caption">Very/long/word</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item">
        <div class="list__item-img"></div>
        <span class="list__item-caption">Very/long/word</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item">
        <div class="list__item-img"></div>
        <span class="list__item-caption">Very/long/word</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item">
        <div class="list__item-img"></div>
        <span class="list__item-caption">Very/long/word</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item">
        <div class="list__item-img"></div>
        <span class="list__item-caption">Very/long/word</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item">
        <div class="list__item-img"></div>
        <span class="list__item-caption">Very/long/word</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item">
        <div class="list__item-img"></div>
        <span class="list__item-caption">Very/long/word</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item">
        <div class="list__item-img"></div>
        <span class="list__item-caption">Very/long/word</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item">
        <div class="list__item-img"></div>
        <span class="list__item-caption">Very/long/word</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `display: flex` on `.list` element instead of using grid? Once that's set, you need to set a `min-width` property for the columns and by using `flex-wrap: wrap` the rows can collapse if the width of the items put together exceeds the full width of the container.

Comment: This approach will break general width of each column. Last items will have not the same with as previous ones